# print isduplicate from array of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Find duplicate value from nested array at 1st index if duplicate found show row first is duplicate if not should say this row is not not duplicate

```
var array = [
      ["fruits", "Apple", "vegetable", "Potato"],
      ["fruits", "Mango", "vegetable", "Tomoto"],
      ["fruits", "Apple", "vegetable", "Carrot"]
    ];

const counter = {}

array.flat().forEach(i => counter[i] ? counter[i]++ : counter[i] = 1);

const dupes =Object.entries(counter)
  .filter(([k, v]) => v > 1)
  .map(([k,v])=> k);
  
function myFunction() {
  text = array.map(i => !dupes.some(d=> i.includes(d)));

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Tried that code and says all are false it should check first index to all array and print value.

In that case it should says First row is duplicate, second row is not duplicate and third row is duplicate as Apple exists in first and third row. It should only check with first index.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? All arrays have "fruits" so they all have duplicated.

Comment: No First index "Apple" is available is available in other raw's first index

Comment: If arrays index of first index and array of second index matches with raw then should say false otherwise true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

For each set in the array, the first index is checked, and value and set index is recorded. Then, after all sets have been processed, an array of results is created from the recorded indexes.

```js
var array = [
  ["fruits", "Apple", "vegetable", "Potato"],
  ["fruits", "Mango", "vegetable", "Tomoto"],
  ["fruits", "Apple", "vegetable", "Carrot"]
];

// Loop through sets
// Check index=1, check obj for key
//  If doesn't exist, create it with one element array containing index
//  If does exist, add duplicate index to array

function findFirstIndexDupes(arr) {
  var dupesObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (dupesObj[arr[i][1]] == undefined)
      dupesObj[arr[i][1]] = [i];
    else
      dupesObj[arr[i][1]].push(i);

  var output = Array(arr.length).fill(true);

  for (var dupe in dupesObj)
    if (dupesObj[dupe].length > 1)
      dupesObj[dupe].forEach(e => output[e] = false);
  return output;
}

console.log(findFirstIndexDupes(array));
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips what if I wanted to check index of 2 as well. I mean it should compare index of 1 and index of 2. Please guide on that I tried doesn't work thanks

Comment: If I put vegetables in third raw it should say true everywhere because apple does exists in 1st index but not same as third index

Comment: Do you mean index of 3? Checking the vegetable names as well as the fruits?

Comment: It should check Apple and vegetable are same in each row then return false otherwise true

Comment: So instead of comparing across rows, just checking whether index 1 (eg. "Apple") is equal to index 2 (eg. "vegetable")?